# Get existing parameters from JPA Specification

Tags: java, jpa, predicate, specifications

I have a JPA Specification provided by an existing framework. I want to add a value to the Specification **only if there is already a specific Predicate in the Specification**.

Example pseudo code:

```
public getBook(Specification specification) {
    if ( **check here if specification already has a predicate for X=Y** ) {
       spcecification.or(...)
    }
}
```

or maybe here

```
static Specification<Book> titleContains(String title) {
    return (book, cq, cb) -> {
        if ( **check here if specification already has a predicate for X=Y** ) {
          cb.like(book.get("title"), "%" + title + "%"
        }
    });
}
```

How do I check existing values of the specification?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. I am not asking to execute SQL X=Y, I am asking how do i see if my query already contains that sub query. I see no way of interrogating the existing predicate for to scan for existing values.

Comment: Even just printing out the proposed SQL of before execution might help